# How to get big picture from feed (now)? Api has been changed

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I just noticed that Facebook has been changed on retrieving the picture url from feed. Usually I replace _s with _n and I get the "normal" image.

Now I get somthings like this:

https://scontent-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xfp1/v/t1.0-9/p130x130/10527490_10152146397901714_1807442783989783336_n.jpg?oh=a4035ad97f2fa1f9a5cf1612e2195662&oe=542053AD

which is only "small". How can I get the bigger one?

Comment: How did you retrieve this URL?

Comment: Using Graph API: https://graph.facebook.com/UserID/posts?access_token=token

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should ideally be using graph api to get pictures.
If however, you need to get bigger image from these type of url links.
First retreive their final url after 302 redirect :

> h ttps://scontent-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xfp1/**v/t1.0-9/p130x130**/10527490_10152146397901714_1807442783989783336_n.jpg?oh=a4035ad97f2fa1f9a5cf1612e2195662&oe=542053AD

Remove the bold part, and you will get the original image:

https://scontent-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xfp1/10527490_10152146397901714_1807442783989783336_n.jpg?oh=a4035ad97f2fa1f9a5cf1612e2195662&oe=542053AD

**EDIT** : This method does not work anymore,graph api is the best way to go.

Comment: But I'm using Graph API to retrieve this data :O The fact is, in JSON I can get only "picture": "https://scontent-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xfp1/v/t1.0-9/p130x130/10527490_10152146397901714_1807442783989783336_n.jpg?oh=a4035ad97f2fa1f9a5cf1612e2195662\u0026oe=542053AD",

Comment: Is that `v/t1.0-9/p130x130` standard? Or it can be different? And what do you suggest for retrieve this kind of picture?

Comment: I mean: if tomorrow Facebook changes to `v/t1.0-10` it will fail. There isn't any safe way to get original image without this kind of "replace"?

Comment: @BartBurg Yes,it may not,as it was a hack based on url format at that time. Best way is to use graph api itself.

Comment: But im also getting the link from graph api,so i dont understand how graph api is the bets solution.

my query is 

https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?fields=feed.limit(10).fields(shares,picture,full_picture,link,source,status_type,caption)&access_token=mytoken

do i need to change the query?