# How to get a larger scraped feed picture?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I read the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/post?locale=it_IT), and the scraped feed picture is stored inside the `picture` tag.
Unfortunately, it returns a small version of the picture. I need a larger one.

How can I do it this Graph API? Seems that API/workarounds [have been changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24606300/how-to-get-big-picture-from-feed-now-api-has-been-changed).
No way anymore? Can't find anything in the Facebook documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
/post-id?fields=picture.type(large)
/post-id?fields=picture.width(100).height(100)
```

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2?locale=en_US#fieldexpansion

Edit: Actually, it does not seem to work for the user feed, but there is an "object_id" in the result of `/me/feed`. You can do another request to that object_id:

```
/object-id
```

...resulting in all the available images sizes:

```
"images": [
    {
      "height": 526,
      "source": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/v/t1.0-9/10444402_888067974538310_2165197996181662459_n.jpg?oh=4518cc6608a14a2108aeaf61bcb60d09&oe=5501E78D&__gda__=1426703335_d71feeeb9aa6d8fd58085cd6074101e3",
      "width": 526
    },
    {
      "height": 480,
      "source": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/v/t1.0-9/p480x480/10444402_888067974538310_2165197996181662459_n.jpg?oh=bc0736fc9f74b1a4d89727ae5526dd3b&oe=5517CD73&__gda__=1427230414_1197a9870346dbaaf300c2ea0e359402",
      "width": 480
    },
...
```

Comment: Nope. It returns the small version of the picture: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=888067974538310%3Ffields%3Dpicture.type%28large%29&version=unversioned

Comment: ok, that id already is an object-id/photo-id, just take a look at the images array in the result: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=888067974538310 - the first one is always the largest one.

Comment: i´ve added the important result in my answer, take a look

Comment: Perfect! With one-more call to that object id I get whatever I want. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

New way - /{post_id}?fields=full_picture